# Can't get full screen buttons to work with highcharts-vue

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

I'm using the `highcharts-vue` wrapper within my `vue` project. Things are going smooth except for the fact that I can't get the `viewFullscreen` option to work.

I've set things up following the [docs](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue) and included the following within my `main.js`

```
import exportingInit from 'highcharts/modules/exporting'`
exportingInit(Highcharts);
```

The export function is working within my charts. For every chart I've set up the options as follow:

```
exporting: {
        buttons: {
            contextButton: {
                menuItems: ['viewFullScreen', 'downloadPNG', 'downloadJPEG', 'downloadPDF']
            }
        }
    }
```

alle the buttons ar visible and working except for the `viewFullscreen` button. that one isn't showing.

Following the [docs](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems) from the `highcharts` `api` there isn't anything mentioned about having to include extra options or so to make use of the `vieFullscreen` mode.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the first string from `viewFullScreen` to `viewFullscreen`:

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        contextButton: {
            menuItems: ['viewFullscreen', 'downloadPNG', 'downloadJPEG', 'downloadPDF']
        }
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ekr2mw7f/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I've changed it butt still no luck

Comment: Hi @dexter, Which Highcharts version do you use?

Comment: Following my `package.json`: `"highcharts": "^7.0.3",
"highcharts-vue": "^1.2.0"`

Comment: Please check the newest Highcharts version - 7.1.1.